# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...markedDates.push...')

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I was developing an app using React Native, the following problem occurred.

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...markedDates.push...')

I'm trying to put the following data into markedDates.

```
{'2023-03-03': {marked: true, dotColor: 'blue'}}
```

However, I searched a lot of information, but I couldn't find a situation that corresponds to my situation.

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {Calendar} from "react-native-calendars";
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  var dateString = "";
  var markedDates = {
    '2023-02-01': {marked: true, dotColor: 'red'},
  }

  markedDates.push({'2023-03-03': {marked: true, dotColor: 'blue'}});
  return(
      <SafeAreaProvider>
         <View>
            <Calendar
              markedDates={markedDates}
              onDayPress={(day) => {
                
              }}
           />
         </View>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Is there anyone who can solve this problem? If so, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markedDates` is initialized as an object, not an array. Therefore, you cannot use the `push()` method on it.